# How Tailwind show big image actual size in a overflow-auto div

Tags: tailwind-css

I have let my user select an image preview in `div`, and then crop an area to upload an image.

Now I have a problem with how to show the image's actual size in a `div` with Tailwind-CSS.

For example, `a.jpg` size is `3000px` X `2500px`.

```html
<body class="antialiased">
    <div class="w-2/3 mx-auto">
        <div class="relative overflow-auto">
            <img src="/a.jpg" class="w-full" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The size of the image is reduced to fit inside the `div`, so `overflow-auto` didn't work.

I want to show both `x` and `y` scrollbars, can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `h-max` and `w-max` to the image's container. This way, your container will always scale according to the image's width and height.

Example:

```html
<body class="antialiased">
  <div class="h-max w-max">
    <img src="https://s1.1zoom.me/big3/371/363095-commander06.jpg"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/shgeSwFzts)

---

If you don't want to change your layout, you can create another separate container for the `h-max` and `w-max` utilities:

```html
<body class="antialiased">
  <div class="mx-auto w-2/3">
    <div class="overflow-auto">
      <div class="h-max w-max">
        <img src="https://s1.1zoom.me/big3/371/363095-commander06.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/LVYXw6OqmD)

---

You can also limit the area by adding custom width and height to the middle container:

```html
<body class="antialiased">
  <div class="mx-auto w-2/3">
    <div class="overflow-auto h-[300px] w-[500px]">
      <div class="h-max w-max">
        <img src="https://s1.1zoom.me/big3/371/363095-commander06.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/yxZSkFTlbf)

Comment: I don't think this arbitrary value approach will work. Judging from how the OP described it, they will probably need to set the height and width _programmatically_ - the sizes were merely an example, so you can't just take `3000px`/`2500px` measurements for granted. Setting things programmatically introduces a new problem since Tailwind won't be able to scan for the rules you set programmatically, and therefore will simply not create the CSS output for it in the application build.

Comment: @ChenBr i can't hardcoded the width and height in the div, because user may be upload a small or big image, so i expect `overflow-auto` will handle the xy scrollbar base on the image size, i have write some script to get the input file object then preview in the div and get the croped position send to backend, all worked fine, so if the image size reduced on the screen, the croped position is incorrect.

Comment: @gyohza, You're right about it. I edited my answer with both approaches. There's no debate that making it programmatically is much better. kenken9999, Please take a look at my edit. Does it achieve what you wanted?

Comment: @ChenBr with use `h-max` and `w-max` will break the layout, because the scrollbar isn't showing inside the div, thats why i make an example for use `w-2/3 mx-auto`, the scrollbar should inside this div

Comment: @kenken9999, I added this option in my answer as well. Please take a look and let me know if I understood you correctly :)

Comment: @ChenBr OMG, the 2nd code block worked, this one `If you don't want to change your layout.....` , remove other code block, let me mark it as answer, tyvm, or can you create a new reply, only of the second code block

Comment: @kenken9999, Happy I could eventually help you :) I updated my answer with all the necessary/relevant code (the first three blocks). I think this way, more examples make it clear and understandable for someone who might occur a similar issue